# Impute mean based on cluster

Tags: classification, clustering, python, missing-data, scikit-learn

I have a binary classification task with high class imbalance - the mean y is 0.014.  Data consists of 100,000 rows and 40 columns. If I select rows where no column is NA I only get 10,000 rows back i.e. there are many NAs.

I know how to impute mean in python:

```
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0) #column wise
imp.fit(X)
X = imp.transform(X)
```

I want to first group observations clusters (e.g. via PCA or another method), then **impute the mean based on clusters**. Question: Is it (i) statistically sensible and (ii) possible in python?

I think I might use the following methods:

- logistic regression
- KNN
- Neural networks

Answer (score 1):

Questions about Python are off topic here.

Statistically, if 90% of your data is missing, you have some serious problems. Imputing the mean, either the overall mean or the cluster mean, is going to cause problems.

Missing data is a huge area. There are lots of methods and the proper method depends on many factors.  The most important is probably whether the data are missing completely at random (MCAR), missing at random (MAR) or missing not at random.  Also important is whether the missingness is monotone or not.

But with so much missing data, I'd be very leery of any solution.